# How to scrape the next page in ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I am trying to scrape the next page of the website called `https://www.jobsatosu.com/postings/search`. Because there are many jobs, there are many pages. Our team successfully scraped the first page like this:

```
def initialize
        @agent_menu = Mechanize.new
        @page = @agent_menu.get(PAGE_URL)
        @form = @page.forms[0]
```

I am working on trying to scrape the next page. Also, we were told to use Nokogiri and Mechanize in Ruby. I just have to scrape the next page and do not have to parse it.

This is what I did:

```
def next_page
        @page_num += 1
        new_url = "https://www.jobsatosu.com/postings/search?page=#{@page_num}"
        @new_page = @agent_menu.get(new_url)
        @new_form = @new_page.forms[0]
    end
```

I made one `page_num` for all to share. If someone calls the method, then it gets iterated by 1 and it gets the new URL, puts it in `@new_page`.
I haven't tested this out, but any thoughts on this code?

Comment: I'd recommend reading "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". Your question doesn't mention having a problem with the code so you want a code-review? If so, SO isn't really the right place as it's a site to help with coding problems. Once the code is written and working then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would possibly be a better fit.

Comment: To clarify, you loaded the page, you didn't scrape it. Scraping is when you actually retrieve information from the contents of the page. Typically, we don't scrape with Mechanize, though it's possible because Nokogiri underlies it; Nokogiri is the proper tool for scraping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `@page_num = 0` before use

In the first time `@page_num` is nil so `@page_num += 1` **raises execption**

`NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`

Actually you don't describe variable before using but in this case, you need to do